# Firebase >> User Favorites List

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need a little assistance with my app. I'm not asking for a handout, just some guidance as to where to begin. The basic idea is for logged in users to be able to favorite videos, and to have them persist when logged in.

My app uses the YouTube API (Playlist Items) to display videos from my public playlists within my app. I'm using firebase auth to register and login users, but I have yet to implement the RTD. This is where I need some assistance in structuring my data & organizing my app.

I don't want favorite lists created for every user by default, nor do I want to store false values and have to loop through them. I'd only like to set a favorites list if the user requests to do so, and the values are true. I'm open to suggestions regarding structuring my data, but I was thinking something simple like this:

```
"favorites": {
    "John Doe": {
        "video1ID": true,
        "video2ID": true,
    }
}
```

Videos are contained within cards using a .each function from within the API response. Included in these cards are "favorite" toggle switches that I'd like a user to be able to toggle and add a favorite video to their list.

YouTube provides Video ID's from within their JSON response. I was thinking that assigning a boolean to that video ID would get the job done, but I have no idea where to begin.

Something like:

```
function writeFavoritesList (name, videoID, toggleValue) {
firebase.database().ref('favorites/' + userId).set({
name: displayName,
videoID: videoID,
toggleValue: true
});
}
```

I'm very much a newb to anything outside of WordPress, so I hope I'm on the right track. Any help appreciated. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks great. If this were another database, you could consider storing the video IDs in an array, but this being the firebase RealTime Database, you're much better off with objects, which you've already got.

You could modify your structure slightly to take advantage of RTDs push() key generation if you ever intend on sorting your favourite videos. To do so, instead of making the key the videoID and the value the boolean status, you could generate a key using firebase's push() key generation and make the value the videoID. "The unique key generated by push() are ordered by the current time, so the resulting list of items will be chronologically sorted. The keys are also designed to be unguessable (they contain 72 random bits of entropy)."

```
"favorites": {
    "uid1": {
        "uniqueKey1": videoID1,
        "uniqueKey2": videoID2,
    }
}
```

To generate a push() key, use: `const key = firebase.database().ref().push().key`.

More info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push

Answer (score 2):

Saw your [Guru](https://www.guru.com/jobs/cloud-firestore-user-favorites-list/1434399) post. I think the best way for you to learn is to delve deep into the documentation and figure this out for yourself. If you're truly committed to learning this stuff you'd be doing yourself a disservice to have someone else write the code for you.

I'd start with the GCP(Google Cloud Platform) cloud firestore docs and read through the Concepts section in its entirety:
 https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts

The firebase site mirrors parts of the GCP documenation, but also covers client implementations:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/

To get the most out of these docs use the nav sidebar on the left to drill down into all the various Cloud Firestore topics. They go into how to structure your database and provide sample code for you to analyse and play with.

You'll see the terms **Documents** and **Collections** thrown around a lot. A **Document** is somewhat equivalent to a JSON Object. A **Collection** is a list of documents; similar to an array of JSON objects. But here's where things get interesting; **Documents** can reference **Collections** (aka **Subcollections**):

So I would structure your database as follows:

- Create a **Users** collection
- Whenever a new user signs into your app, create a **user** document and add it to the **Users** collection.
- The first time a user selects a favorite video create a **Favorites** collection and add it to the **user** document; then add **favorite** documents to the **Favorites** collection for this user

There is a Javascript/Web client (you've seem to already have it loaded from what I've seen in the repo link you provided on Guru). Here's the reference documentation for it:
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore
The classes, methods and properties defined in those reference docs are what you'll be calling from within your jquery code blocks.

Good luck and stick with it.

Comment: OP mentions Firebase not Firestore just FYI.  :-)

Comment: @Joel OP decided to leverage Firestore later on as detailed in the Guru link (a month after his post here on stack). Wasn't about to waste my credits on guru, figured I'd chime in here. Thanks for the "FYI" though.